# "Run | Debug" option showing above each test in Eclipse using TestNG and Selenium

Tags: eclipse, testng

I recently had to install fresh Eclipse and TestNG, and now this new option is showing above each test. I'd like to remove it but I can't find a configuration for it. Any ideas?

["Run | Debug" option showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATGMB.png)

Edit: It seems to always display under the @Test. When I remove that, the option goes away.

Comment: I had the exact opposite problem, I went from an old install of eclipse to a new install (and newer version).  I wondered why in that newer version, my test methods no longer showed "run" "debug", nor was there a "run all" at the top.  After verifying that I still saw the "decorations" in the older eclipse for the same project, I reopened the new version, realized it was vanilla (no plugins) save for STS installed, added testNG in the marketplace, installed.  Restarted eclipse.  Mystery (newb mistake) solved!  Decorations are back!  These Q&A's helped to solve, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

These decorations in the Java text editor are called "[Code Minings](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.10/jdt.php#jdt-codemining)".

You can disable them by visiting: **Preferences > Java > Editor > Code Minings**.

While you can easily disable the decorations altogether, unfortunately I haven't found a way to disable just the ones related to TestNG.

[image: Image of the Eclipse Java Code Minings preferences dialog.]

Answer (score -1):

These are simple Run or debug options.
If you click on Run-> It will run the respective scenario.
If you click on Debug-> It will run the respective scenario on Debug mode.

Comment: Answer does not answer the question that was asked